# Visibility Component props not firing - Semantic UI React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, visibility, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to get infinite scroll working on my Semantic UI React app, using the Visibility Component.

I've been following this example on the Semantic UI React page: https://react.semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility#callback-frequency-example. I've simplified the code as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Visibility } from 'semantic-ui-react';

export default class VisibilityExample extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Visibility
                continuous={false}
                once={false}
                onTopVisible={() => console.log('test')}
                onTopPassed={() => console.log('test')}
                onBottomVisible={() => console.log('test')}
                onBottomPassed={() => console.log('test')}
                onTopVisibleReverse={() => console.log('test')}
                onTopPassedReverse={() => console.log('test')}
                onBottomVisibleReverse={() => console.log('test')}
                onBottomPassedReverse={() => console.log('test')}
                onPassing={() => console.log('test')}
                onPassingReverse={() => console.log('test')}
                onOnScreen={() => console.log('test')}
                onOffScreen={() => console.log('test')}
            >
                <div>Hello</div>
            </Visibility>
        );
    }
}
```

In my simple React App, none of the `console.log` statements are firing. However, when I manipulate the code on the Semantic UI React webpage, the `console.log` statements are fired as expected.

What am I missing?

Edit: Here is where I'm rendering the VisibilityExample component, in an `index.js` file:

```
/* global document */

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import VisibilityExample from './VisibilityExample';

ReactDOM.render(
    <VisibilityExample />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: where did you use the `VisibilityExample` component? Show us that JS file as well

Comment: Try with a different browser and see and there is a reported bug for google chrome. I'm not sure whether it has fixed right now.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan just modified my answer to include where I'm rendering the `VisibilityExample` component -- it's a really simple file. I tried in Firefox as well, no luck

Comment: It is not working for me either. And my page is large enough to cause a scroll bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Events of Visibility component only fire when you scroll the container of the component. Because all these events are based on the default [window scroll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) event.

But if you only have the given code, it won't have any scroll bars hence scroll events. So you need to add some `div`s with arbitrary heights to get the scroll bars and scroll content to see `console.log` statements are firing.

See this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/D99mwMy9B

Comment: Thank you! It works now. Do you know if it's possible to detect the scroll in the container of the component instead of the window's scroll? Would love to scroll say a dropdown component instead.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see `context` in Semantic UI React: https://react.semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility. Whereas it is present in regular Semantic UI: https://semantic-ui.com/behaviors/visibility.html. DO you know if this is the only way to change the scroll detection to a component rather than window?

Comment: It seems that's not possible with Visibility component. It always based on window events and window properties. Look at the source code. https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/blob/master/src/behaviors/Visibility/Visibility.js#L169